# What is the first day of the week in crontab?

Tags: cron

So we know that the fifth column in crontab means day of the week. But what day is considered as 1? What is considered the first day of the week? Is it Sunday or Monday?

Comment: FYI I think the reason for the downvotes on your question is because it's something that's easily searchable; a search for "crontab day of week" actually turns up [this SO question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919151/crontab-day-of-the-week-syntax) that explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, etc.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

```
   The time and date fields are:

          field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          ...
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
```